# Custom background for current users

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to enable use users to change the theme of their profile to whatever they like. It doesn't work well. When one user changes his/her background it effects everyother user profile. Any ideas on how this can be achieved. My code looks like below.

```
<?php 
    global $current_user;

    get_currentuserinfo();

    // User Background Choice

    if ($current_user->user_cutom_background= "Sports")
    {
        $myBg= "image.jpg"; 
?>
    <style type="text/css"> 
    body {
    background-image: url("<?php echo $myBg;?>");
   }

    </style>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Save for each user the custom bg in their specific user dataset in your users table and load that data.

Comment: Where does the `$current_user` object come from? You have not created it, and you have not set it to this user

Comment: If you don't know how to make a column in your users table and save/retrieve data in it, then maybe you should look at some basic tutorials.

Comment: If you dont post it, we cannot help

Comment: Not good enough. Where is `get_currentuserinfo();` it is not in scope as far as I can see. If the code you show us cannot possibly work how can we help

Comment: Then that is the problem, this code cannot possibly work. You are so far from your goal we have no clue how to help

Comment: That is because you're not storing anything unique for each user by using cookies or using a database entry for each user.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois you shouldn't need to create a column in the users table you can us key/value pairs in the user_meta table, but that's what [update_user_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using assignment operator instead of equality operator.

Instead of -

`if ($current_user->user_cutom_background= "Sports")`

do

`if ($current_user->user_cutom_background == "Sports")`.

To eliminate such mistakes you can put the value first like this -

`if ("Sports" == $current_user->user_cutom_background)`

this way if you would do

`if ("Sports" = $current_user->user_cutom_background)`

it will throw an error